# Removing display: none when changing between @media sizes

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two divs. When the resolution is large enough, both divs are shown next to each other. But when the resolution is too small it only shows one of the divs, but I can toggle between them with two buttons appearing at this resolution.

So my HTML is just like this:

```
<div id="buttons">
    <p>LEFT</p>
    <p>RIGHT</p>
</div>
<div id="left"> CONTENT </div>
<div id="right"> CONTENT </div>
```

The JavaScript used for the toggle is just:

```
<script>
    $(function() {   
        $('#buttons> p').click(function() {
            var ix = $(this).index();

            $('#left').toggle( ix === 0 );
            $('#right').toggle( ix === 1 );
        });
    });
</script>
```

Basically everything works fine. When the resolution is too small, the buttons pop up, and it is divided into one div at a time, and when the resolution is large enough they are next to each other.
However, if I change the width of my browser window, and toggle between the two divs, and then go back, one of the divs still has `display: none` resulting in it not showing when there has been toggled.
I know one might argue that people don't change resolutions on phones, and therefore this shouldn't be a problem. But somehow it annoys me a lot. So I was wondering if there was some way to tell it, that if above a certain resolution, BOTH divs should have the `display: none` or inline style removed.

Comment: Run a check for `$(window).resize()` and put in an `if` statement checking for window width.

Comment: You can detect the width of the window using `window.innerWidth`. So you detect when it greater than certain width you remove the `display` properties on your element. Or like @disinfor said, listen to resize on window.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a `resize` listener to show both elements if the size is sufficiently high:

```js
$('#buttons> p').click(function() {
  var ix = $(this).index();
  $('#left').toggle(ix === 0);
  $('#right').toggle(ix === 1);
});
$(window).resize(function() {
  if (Number($(window).width()) > 600) $('#left, #right').show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="buttons">
  <p>LEFT</p>
  <p>RIGHT</p>
</div>
<div id="left"> CONTENT1 </div>
<div id="right"> CONTENT2 </div>
```

Comment: Is it possible to take into account the scroll bar ? If I'm not mistaken, this code looks at the window excluding the scroll bar. So if there is a scroll bar, it actually show the div a bit late compared to the other media queries I have because the scroll bar has some finite width. And then of course, if there is no scroll bar it works as intended.

Answer (score 0):

use media queries for setting different css based on screen size. PFb sample. you can also add display style as css as None or Block based on screen width.

```
body {
        background-color: red;
    }
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    body {
        background-color: lightblue;
    }
}
```

Comment: That is what I'm doing. But my javascript uses inline styling when hiding/showing divs. And they override the CSS, so if it has an inline styling of `display: none`, and I switch back to where both should be visible, one still has the `display: none` inline styling.